# Can Server broadcast the max number of examples to every client in a train cycle in FL? Is this action an invasion of privacy?

Tags: tensorflow-federated

I am training a FL model. I select 5 clients every cycle. I want to get the examples gap between a client and the maximum quantity client. Can Server broadcast the max number of examples among the 5 clients to others during this cycle? Is it legal?

Answer (score 0):

In TFF it is definitely possible to implement broadcasting additional information. The API is [`tff.federated_broadcast`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/federated_broadcast) and if you're looking to extend it in a Federated Averaging algorithm, re-using the [`simple_fedavg`](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/tree/master/tensorflow_federated/python/research/simple_fedavg) implementation it could probably be added [near here](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/3fcd5317f436a45eb01a071d5210d34492543e52/tensorflow_federated/python/research/simple_fedavg/simple_fedavg_tff.py#L126).

Regarding whether something is an invasion pf privacy maybe useful to ask "what do other participants learn about each other?" and "should the information learned be considered sensitive?". A very strict interpretation of privacy might be "other participants learn nothing" and "all information is sensitive".

We can imagine a scenario where the server picks a maximum number of examples to process, not based on any data from the clients, and tells/broadcasts this number to each client. It seems unlikely the server or other participants would be able to learn something about an individual participant, nor something sensitive, since the number does is not derived from client data.

Alternatively, the server might first learn how many examples each client has, and then broadcast that number back to all the clients. This is definitely sharing something about one client with all other participants. It might also be sensitive, in particular if each client has a different number of examples and that number might now be used to uniquely identify a client.